# What is the group_interval for the alerts which does not have group_by field?

Tags: prometheus, webhooks, prometheus-alertmanager

As I can check that they are grouped as Not grouped alerts. Are they behave like a group or individual??

In my case alertmanager config, group_by is set as namespace. I fired two alerts with different name but with no namespace labels at an interval of 130 second. group_interval is 5m. The first alert is notified immediately to webhook, but other alert is notified only after 5 minut from the previous notification.